# How to add HTMLDocument Element to a JSX Template for a StencilJS Component

Tags: javascript, typescript, jsx, stenciljs

Newbie question in StencilJS v1.0.7 here. 
I am trying to add a HTMLElement to a JSX Template, that get's return and render by StencilJS. But not getting any wanted result. 
I am not sure if this a bug or a missing a very simple step.

1. I have tried simply adding element but get
2. Then tried htmlList.outerHTML but get >
3. I know that  exists but don't know right way to apply it in my case.

```
// @stencil/core v1.0.7 
import { Component, h } from '@stencil/core';
@Component({
  tag: 'my-component',
  styleUrl: 'my-component.css',
  shadow: true
})
export class MyComponent {
  render() {
    let htmlList=[
      <img src="https://example.com/test1.jpg" />,
      <img src="https://example.com/test2.jpg" />,
    ];
    // createElement
    window.console.log("Start createElement");
    let element = document.createElement('img');
    // Apply DOM Logic
    element.setAttribute('src', 'https://example.com/test3.jpg');
    // TODO Convert ??
    // Append to htmlList
    window.console.log(element);
    htmlList.push(element);
    // Try outerHTML
    window.console.log(element.outerHTML);
    htmlList.push(element.outerHTML);
    window.console.log("End createElement");
    // EOF createElement
    return <div>{htmlList}</div>;
  }
}
```

On Firefox or Chrome I've only got this and not wanted html.

Log Grab
my-component.entry.js?s-hmr=326127425623:19 Start createElement
my-component.entry.js?s-hmr=326127425623:25 ​
my-component.entry.js?s-hmr=326127425623:28 
my-component.entry.js?s-hmr=326127425623:30 End createElement

Html Grab

```html
<div><img src="https://example.com/test1.jpg"><img src="https://example.com/test2.jpg"><undefined></undefined>&lt;img src="https://example.com/test3.jpg"&gt;</div>
```

> Blockquote

If modify above with

```html
<div><div innerHTML={htmlList.join("")}></div></div> then 
[object Object][object Object][object HTMLImageElement]
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh stupid me! To anyone like me on Earth what comes along this problem. Here is answer :)

To add a HTMLElement to a JSXElement in StencilJS (at least) the recommend way is "" what is in the docs.

Therefore to solve my question:

Replace above with

```
let htmlList=[
  '<img src="https://example.com/test1.jpg" />',
  '<img src="https://example.com/test2.jpg" />',
];
// And htmlList.push(element); with 
htmlList.push(element.outerHTML);
// And finally 
<div><div innerHTML={htmlList.join("")}></div></div>
```